# Time complexity of the following two programs?

Tags: time-complexity, language-agnostic, big-o, conceptual

I know that the time complexity of the following code is O(n).

```py
n = 10
for x in range(0,n): 
    print("")
```

I also know that the time complexity of the following code is O(n^2):

```py
n = 10
for x in range(0,n): 
    for y in range(0,n):
        print("")
```

---

**I am having trouble determining the time complexity of the following two programs.**

1. Here, we have two individual loops. Each has a time complexity of O(n). So, should the time complexity of the whole program be O(n + n)? or something else?

```py
# program 1
 
n = 10
for x in range(0,n): 
    print("")

for y in range(0,n): 
    print("")
```

2. Here, we have two individual loops again but the first loop has a time complexity of O(n^2) and the second loop has a time complexity of O(n^3). So, should the time complexity of the whole program be O(n^2 + n^3)? or something else?

```py
# program 2

n = 10
for x in range(0,n): 
    for y in range(0,n): 
        print("")

for a in range(0,n): 
    for b in range(0,n): 
        for c in range(0,n): 
            print("")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes the complexity of your 2nd program will be O(n^2) + O(n^3). You can conclude that the complexity of your program is just O(n^3) because it is the monomial term that have the biggest power.

The complexity of your first program is O(n) + O(n) = 2.O(n) = O(n). You are reasoning well. The complexity is O(n)

Comment: Thank you for answering. I understood the explanation for 2nd program. But, for the first program, how can we say that 2.O(n) is equal to O(n)?

Comment: Thank you. O represent the asymptotic notation , There are rules to compare asymptotic representation. Given a constant ``c`` such that ``c << n``, then ``c*O(n) ~= O(n)`` otherwise if *c~=n* then ``c*O(n)=n*O(n)``.